# Is there a way to create a peer to peer network on top of substrate?

Tags: offchain-worker, substrate-front-end, offchain-storage, live-network

Most of substrate tutorials are based on on-chain logic so there's not much information on this topic. Is there a way to use Substrate's in-built p2p network for other purposes such as constant sharing of nontext files eg live stream videos, across the blockchain?

Comment: Why would you want to build what sounds like a heavy process into / on top of an already fairly heavy protocol for a chain like this? Why not use a separate derive and network for non chain operations?

Comment: Are you referring to using a separate blockchain for live streaming?

Comment: A separate non blockchain service,like ipfs.